# Sequencing two actions together using an epic in redux-observable

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I am building an application with react-native using redux-observable.
Right now I am struggling to do a simple decoration over two actions in redux-observable by using an epic. What I am trying to achieve is simply to map two actions to one.

The error I am getting is:

```
You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
```

Here is the code I am using:

```js
import { Observable } from 'rx';

export const startApplicationEpic = (action$: Observable) =>
  action$
    .ofType('START_APPLICATION')
    .flatMap(() =>
      Observable.of(
        { type: 'REGISTER_PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS'},
        { type: 'AUTHENTICATION_REQUEST' }
      )
    );
    
// index.js

store.dispatch({ type: 'START_APPLICATION' })
```

To me the RxJS code I am using is valid, and if epics are a stream than this should work, or is it only possible to dispatch a single action from an epic?

Comment: What line throws the error? Are you sure it's somewhere in the code you showed here? Also you probably want to import from `rxjs` and not `rx`.

Comment: I too agree that is suspicious--are you using the v4 adapter (redux-observable-adapter-rxjs-v4) ? If not, you will definitely need to use v5 which is published to npm as `rxjs` not `rx`

Comment: Thank you martin, that was the issue. I needed to use rxjs instead of rx, which is a dependancy of redux-observable, then everything worked fine. I guess under the hood they quite some differences.

Comment: @martin did you want to add that as an answer and he can accept it? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you're importing [rx](https://npmjs.com/package/rx) (which is v4) instead of [rxjs](https://npmjs.com/package/rxjs) (which is v5). So your code is providing a v4 Observable to the `flatMap` of a v5 Observable (redux-observable internals by default give you v5). The two versions cannot interop by default, but there are [temporary interop layers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs-compatibility). I admit this is all pretty confusing.

The best way to use v4 with redux-observable is to include the adapter we created for it [redux-observable-adapter-rxjs-v4](https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable-adapter-rxjs-v4). If if you are using v4 on accident or it otherwise doesn't make a difference, definitely use v5 instead.

Once you fix that, the code as provided works as expected, without errors: https://jsbin.com/xiqigi/edit?js,console

Comment: I was banging my head for 2 hours and didn't check the projects dependancies. Thank you for the input.